# Хранение данных приложения

Tags: delphi, хранение-данных

У меня возник вопрос касательно хранения данных, используемых приложением. Как лучше это дело реализовать, не используя БД?

Есть, например, приложение, которое позволяет в онлайне формировать формы и визуальные компоненты на них. И нужно где-то хранить информацию об этих компонентах, чтобы при запуске программы они автоматически создавались. Текста будет много, так как нужно хранить тип компонента, его имя, капшн, размеры, местоположение и т.д., поэтому я не думаю, что стоит для этих целей использовать реестр. Я раньше использовал для этого файлы конфигурации (*.ini). Может есть вариант получше?

Прошу жалобы/заявления/предложения.

Comment: однозначно XML

Comment: Почитай про Сериализацию объектов: [Сериализация объектов стандартными средствами Delphi](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/delphi/serialization.xml) [XML сериализация объекта Delphi](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=462)

Answer (score 1):

[XML.](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)

1. *Очень прост, как html тэги(все мы знаем что это)*
2. **Расширяемый**
3. **UTF-8**
4. **XML не зависит от платформы** и т.д.

P.S: в дальнейшем, если надо будет чего то поменять(не сомневаюсь) в настройках приложений, можете без проблем открыт в обычном Notepad -e, без специальных административных утилит.

Comment: XML, конечно, вариант хороший. У него простая, понятная структура, про ограничения в размерах я не слышал. Но чтобы с ним работать нужно писать хорошего размера модуль в программе, который бы осуществлял запись в XML и парсил эти файлы. Я не ищу легких путей, но пока посмотрим, что еще люди скажут.

Comment: > нужно писать хорошего размера модуль в программе, который бы осуществлял запись в XML и парсил эти файлы

Особых проблем быть не должно. В delphi парсер XML есть "из коробки".

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю, чем вас *.ini файлы не устраивают? С ним ни чуть не хуже работать, чем с XML структурами, да и легче даже( если с реестром работали, то наверняка должны знать ). Базы данных, как понимаю, слишком сложно для вас, поэтому **используйте *.ini файлы**. Для вас это будет лучшим выбором. Так, в основном, многие делают, например, если приложение многоязычно. Не искушайтесь, пользуйтесь тем, что предоставили вам разработчики WIndows!

---

Можно, конечно же пользоваться и простыми СУБД, например, "производной" от MySQL - SqLite.
Но не знаю, есть ли компоненты для работы с таким видом баз...наверняка есть, я думаю! Надо только поискать, если правда это так нужно.

Comment: лучше использовать XML, во первых INI действительно "малоудобны", во вторых у INI в зависимости от ОС имеется еще и ограничение на размер в 64кб

Comment: @Vfvtnjd, что-то я не слыхал ни о каком ограничении =) Да, интересно, что за ограничение? На размер файла что ли? lol =)

Comment: @Asen, 
*The Windows API requires that an INI file be less than 64 KB and each section should not exceed 8 KB of memory*
Смотрим:[Working with INI Files in Delphi][1]


  [1]: http://www.delphipages.com/articles/working_with_ini_files_in_delphi-11278.html

Comment: Это в Windows >=2000 были. Читайте в [википедии][1]. Ни о каких ограничениях по размеру и речи нет.

---
Да и вообще, 8кб - это очень много! Порядка 8000 строк. Вт и подумайте.

[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/126863/%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: Я не говорил, что меня не устраивают файлы конфигурации. Я по сей день на них "сижу". Мне просто стало интересно, может есть еще какие-то варианты интересные.

Comment: @Asen, какие 8000 строк? Что, по вашему, такое строка? У меня вот в строке будет тысяча символов, у кого-то 15. 1 килобайт - максимум(!) 1 тысяча символов. Ответ: не более 8000 символов.

Comment: @teanЫЧ, наверняка есть, но о них даже не подозревают вами разработчики Windows =)

---
@xEdelweiss, угу =)

Answer (score 0):

Если хранить надо очень много и знаете SQL, то SQLite вам в помощь. Она маленькая, работает отлично, хранить можете что угодно, использовать с любым другим языком на других системах.

Информации о SQLite + Delphi море. Например, [тут](http://www.delphi.int.ru/articles/43/) или [тут](http://www.webdelphi.ru/2010/09/sqlite-v-delphi-2010/).
Администратор: [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/). *Бесплатен для персонального использования.*
Компоненты: [SQLiteWrapper](http://www.itwriting.com/repos/sqlitewrapper/trunk/) или [SQLite4Delphi](http://sqlite4delphi.sourceforge.net/). *Первой сам пользовался, второй - нет.*

При необходимости, всё можно шифровать: точной ссылки не найду, но начать можно с [темы на форуме](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?bid=69&tid=638226&pg=2).

Comment: @xEdelweiss SQL знаю, но в моем случае это не нужно.